# ScrollView or CollectionView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view populated with data like:

```
[self.graniteImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                               initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Angel Cream", @"name",
                               @"angel-cream.jpg", @"image", nil]];
[self.graniteImages addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                               initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Angola Black", @"name" ,
                               @"angola_black1.jpg", @"image" , nil]];
```

and then have a segue to a detail view which is static.

I now want to add paging to the detail view so that I can swipe through the images that I have contained in my collection view in the same way that the iPhone photo gallery works.

I'm guessing either a scrollview or a second collectionview would be needed however I'm not sure where to start with this so any pointers, sample code or any other help you guys could give would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have a collection view that does what you want just turn on paging. `self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES`  You can also enable paging in IB by checking the paging box in the attributes inspector. Using a `UICollectionView` gives you the added benefit of reusable cells.

### Edit

You could still use UICollectionView. Create an UICollectionViewCell subclass that contains your detail view. Then when you want to launch directly to a particular image you can use `- (void)scrollToItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated` If you're loading a ton of images in this view the scrollview method will load all of your images at once rather than on demand like they would in a collectionview scenario.  You can always work around that in a scrollview but all that work's been done for you in UICollectionView.

### Edit2

I started this in a comment but it was getting big...

In your view controller subclass you will need to register either your class or a nib that you created to lay out that cell.  I prefer the nib so I can lay everything out in Interface Builder.  If you go the nib route you will create an empty xib and drag a UICollectionViewCell out of the object library in the bottom right. Then select that cell and make sure the Class is set to the custom subclass you've created.

Now in your view controller subclass you'll call `– registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` in the viewDidLoad method like this:

```
   [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"WhateverYouNamedYourNib" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```

Your view controller will conform to the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol and you will implement this method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  CustomCellClass *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath
  //Setup the cell with image and whatever else
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: its on the detail view that I want the paging and not on the collection view, I'm using the collection view as the initial grid of images before passing to the detail view for a full screen image.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I misread the question... I updated my answer.

Comment: Brilliant, that sounds good, I'm a complete noob though so I may have a few questions! I've created a subclass of UICollectionViewCell but can't link anything up to it? You may have to explain this as though you're talking to a monkey in a zoo!

Comment: is it the same if I'm using storyboards? I really really appreciate the help here :)

Comment: No storyboards are a different beast.  You create prototype cells in your storyboard. Admittedly I haven't used storyboards so I'm not a great person to ask. I did find this link http://ashfurrow.com/blog/uicollectionview-example from this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530416/how-to-create-uicollectionview-without-using-the-storyboard  It looks like a pretty straight forward walk through

Comment: would it help at all if I send a link to my dropbox with thos project in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30507/discussion-between-david-and-cearwood)

Comment: ok worked out my error but how do I change it so it will auto resize for iPhone 4/4S/5 and iPad???

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use a UIScrollView with paging enabled. The following code should do the trick:

```
NSInteger numberOfImages = [self.graniteImages count];
    CGRect bounds = self.scrollView.bounds;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width * numberOfImages, bounds.size.height);
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

CGFloat x = 0;  
for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in images) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[dict valueForKey:@"image"]]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    x += self.view.bounds.size.width;
}
```

EDIT: This code would go in your detail view controller's ViewDidLoad method. 
Your detail view controller should also have a property index of type NSUInteger and a graniteImages property of type NSMutableArray* that you can set in your collection view controller's prepareForSegue method just like:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"]){
    ((DetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController).graniteImages = self.graniteImages;
    ((DetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController).index = self.tappedImageIndex;
    }
}
```

and in your ViewDidLoad method you add:

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(bounds.size.width * self.index, 0, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) animated:NO];
```

Comment: I'm assuming I would add that code to the detail view and import the main collectionview.h? how would I then set it so that the collection view pushes to the relevant image? oh and can I take the title across as well? sorry really new to all of this!

Comment: check my edited answer, as for the title, you have it already in the NSMutableDictionary *graniteImages, so you can do whatever you like with it! :)