# iOS: UICollectionView stops between cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm implementing UICollectionView but when I scroll the UICollectionView stops between cells:

[image]
Here is muy code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout  alloc] init];
    [layout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    self.collectionView.bounces = YES;
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
    self.collectionView.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight;
}
```

My question to you guys is how to can I stop the UICollectionView to see the complete cell?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: when it stopped, does the app crash?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, it doesn't crash but i see two half cells as you can see the gray line is separator between cells. I just want to show the complete cell

Comment: You'll need to set the cell width equal to collectionView width in storyboard. Also set padding to 0. Still looking for answer?

Answer (score 1):

To scroll one cell at a time you can use `pagingEnabled = YES`, and set the padding between cells to zero:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section   {

    return 0; // No space between cells
  }
```

Check the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378936/scrolling-to-next-cell-in-uicollectionview) question for a detailed discussion about the same topic too.

Comment: Do you know how can make the separator line make it disappear ?

Comment: The line doesn't show only only in the first cell. but the rest of the cells still show the line

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section   {

    return 20; // No space between cells
  }
```

Use this `delegate` method and add space between `section` in `collectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use `targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocit:)`.

Basically you calculate the offset you want the collection view to end on, so you'd want to determine the offset of the closest cell base on the purposed offset and velocity.

This can be a complex task to do correctly but there are a few places I've found that explain the whole thing.

You can checkout [Apple's Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW8) where they explain how you construct your own implementation of this.

This [tutorial](http://blog.karmadust.com/centered-paging-with-preview-cells-on-uicollectionview/) may also be helpful, even though it explains how to center the cells in the middle it should be able to be modified to fit this use case.

I hope this helps.