# UICollectionVIew indexPath.item/row returning incorrect value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, didselectrowatindexpath

Here is the code that I have written for `UICollectionView`. In this `UICollectionView` I'm using a `UIButton` and I want to know the index of cell from where the button was clicked. On button tap the value of `indexPath.item/row` is varying, I'm not getting the correct value.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    frpCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [frpCollectionView setDataSource:self];
    [frpCollectionView setDelegate:self];

    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    frpCollectionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [frpCollectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    [self.view addSubview:frpCollectionView];
    [frpCollectionView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) 
    {
        make.left.and.right.equalTo(self.view);
        make.top.equalTo(self.view);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view);
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return frpTitleArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    frpCollectionViewCell = [frpCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    frpCollectionViewCell.layer.borderWidth=0.25f;
    frpCollectionViewCell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;

    UIButton *setFrpPriceButton = [UIButton new];
    setFrpPriceButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x2196f3);
    [setFrpPriceButton setTitle:@"SET PRICE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [setFrpPriceButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setFrpPriceClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    setFrpPriceButton.tag = selectedCellIndex;

    [frpCollectionViewCell addSubview:setFrpPriceButton];
    setFrpPriceButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
    setFrpPriceButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

    [setFrpPriceButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make)
    {
        make.top.equalTo(frpButtonLabel);
        make.width.equalTo(frpCollectionViewCell).dividedBy(3);
        make.right.equalTo(frpCollectionViewCell);
        make.height.equalTo(frpTitleLabel);
     }];
     return frpCollectionViewCell;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)displaySpecialityCollectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)displaySpecialityCollectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
}

-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)displaySpecialityCollectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)displaySpecialityCollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedCellIndex = (int)[indexPath row];
}
```

Comment: Add code of `setFrpPriceClick` method.

Comment: Why are you setting `setFrpPriceButton.tag = selectedCellIndex;` instead of `setFrpPriceButton.tag = indexPath.row;`

Comment: NSLog(@"row number is %@",setFrpPriceButton.tag);

Comment: @JayeshThanki i tried that as well but it's not working, i am facing the same issue.

Comment: in which method you are write this code `NSLog(@"row number is %@",setFrpPriceButton.tag);` ?

Comment: As said before: Don't add subview to your cell. They are reused! Why is `frpCollectionViewCell` a property? Each time `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called , the value would differ!

Comment: @Larme could you please provide me with a sample code

Comment: `setFrpPriceButton.tag = indexPath.row;` + remove `@property (zzz) UICollectionViewCell * frpCollectionViewCell;` (or assimilated), and use just `UICollectionViewCell *frpCollectionViewCell = [frpCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:ZzZ` That should fix some of your issue. There is still the reuse issue... We also need the code of `setFrpPriceClick`, which clearly should be `setFrpPriceClick:` (to get the tag from the sender).

Comment: @Larme i have made these changes but still i am facing the same issue

Comment: You changed also the signature of the `setFrpPriceClick`? With that kind of code: `-(IBAction)setFrpPriceClick:(id)sender{UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; NSLog(@"CellRow: %ld", [sender tag];}` and `ZzZ action:@selector(setFrpPriceClick:) ZzZ`?

Comment: As Larne mentioned you need to stop creating new button for every time a cell is reused. Try checking in the contentView of the Cell if a button is already present. IF not then try creating a button programatically.
Check this link could of help
https://gist.github.com/linktoming/5417543

Comment: setFrpPriceButton click event i am writing this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method:-

Change

```
setFrpPriceButton.tag = selectedCellIndex;
```

to

```
setFrpPriceButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Also, access button's click event in method "setFrpPriceClick" like this:-

```
-(void)setFrpPriceClick:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[sender tag] inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"row number is %@",indexPath.row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass your cell instead of recreating it each and every time. But anyway, try:

```
[setFrpPriceButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setFrpPriceClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
setFrpPriceButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Your method should look this:

```
    -(void)setFrpPriceClick:(id)sender {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[sender tag] inSection:0];
        NSLog(@"row number is %@",indexPath.row);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to subclass cell with a sample code if possible.

Comment: @CodeGuru you will find useful examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530416/how-to-create-uicollectionview-without-using-the-storyboard

Comment: The code snippets in my answer should work even without subclassing . Did you try @CodeGuru?